# MATLAB column wrap off

Tags: formatting, matlab

I'd like to be able to turn OFF column wrapping in matlab.

So when you see a large matrix in the workspace, it usually goes:

```
  Columns 1 through 12
   -0.3304   -0.1194  ... (( more values! ))
    0.9992   -0.7722

  Columns 13 through 14

   -0.4113   -0.9801
    0.3187   -0.3187
```

i don't want this though.. i want all columns to just scroll to the right, so there is no wrapping

Answer (score 2):

I also wished the same thing a while ago, and wrote a function:
[sites.google.com/site/programmingtipsite/3-math-numerical-analysis#show_matrix_columnwise](http://sites.google.com/site/programmingtipsite/3-math-numerical-analysis#show_matrix_columnwise)

Appreciate any comments for improvement...